# Catch 'open link from external link-call' event

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I'm searching for an event which triggers when an external Desktop-Software like Outlook, Thunderbird, Messenger App etc. want the default browser (firefox) to open a new link. I could manage with a workaround to catch this event if firefox was closed before:

```
// catch page when triggered by link and browser was closed
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function () {
  // search for initial tab
  chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true,
  }, function (tabs) {
    var initialTab = tabs[0];
    // catch open of files and links when browser was closed
    if (initialTab.url != 'chrome://newtab/') {
      handleNewUrlRequest(initialTab.id,initialTab.url);
    }
  });
});
```

But how to catch the opening of an external link when firefox is already running?

Thank you for your help and greetings!

Comment: You can use chrome.webNavigation, but it's tricky: you need two events - 1) onBeforeNavigate event fires with frameId:0 and processId:-1, then 2) immediately onCommitted event fires with transitionType:start_page.

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm I'll posted my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @wOxxOm ill made it in this way:

```
// catch page when triggered by link and browser is already open (firefox) step 1
var lastRequest = null;

chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(function (details) {
  if(details.url == 'about:blank' &&  details.frameId == 0 && details.parentFrameId == -1 && details.transitionType == 'link') {
    lastRequest = details;
  }
});

// catch page when triggered by link and browser is already open (firefox) step 2
chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(function (details) {
  if(lastRequest && details.frameId == 0 && details.parentFrameId == -1 && details.tabId == lastRequest.tabId && details.windowId == lastRequest.windowId) {
    console.log('New Request detected: open new Link in Firefox when Firefox is already open');
    lastRequest = null;
  }
});
```